# How to sort a dictionary in asc or desc with negative and positive keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to sort a python dictionary with negative and positives as keys.

Ex:

```
{
  "-25": 0,
  "-24": 0,
  "-26": 1,
  "-23": 1,
  "-3": 1,
  "-2": 1,
  "-4": 3,
  "-9": 4,
  "-6": 6,
  "-10": 7,
  "-22": 8,
  "-7": 9,
  "-5": 9,
  "-19": 10,
  "-8": 11,
  "0": 4,
  "-16": 16,
  "-14": 16,
  "-12": 16,
  "-21": 17,
  "-15": 17,
  "1": 4
  "-11": 17,
  "-20": 19,
  "-13": 20,
  "-18": 24,
  "-17": 26
}
```

and the expected output would be

```
{
  "-26": 1,      
  "-25": 0,
  "-24": 0,
  "-23": 1,
  "-22": 8,
  "-21": 17,
  "-20": 19,
  "-19": 10,
  "-18": 24,
  "-17": 26
  "-16": 16,
  "-15": 17,
  "-14": 16,
  "-13": 20,
  "-12": 16,
  "-11": 17,
  "-10": 7,
  "-9": 4,
  "-8": 11,
  "-7": 9,
  "-6": 6,
  "-5": 9,
  "-4": 3,
  "-3": 1,
  "-2": 1,
  "0": 4,
  "1": 4
}
```

I have tried sorting with the following code. But it is not able to sort properly as the keys are strings and it is not able to sort in the way I wanted.

```
dict(sorted(dict_to_sort.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this? ```dict(sorted(dict_to_sort.items(), key=lambda item: int(item[0])))```, considering that every key is DEFINITELY a number, in string format, this should work.

Comment: @Moosefeather, yes, sorry, I didn't pay attention to the actual index of the item. I updated my comment as well as per your observation.

Comment: as an aside: maybe you want to convert your keys to actual integers rather than strings?  E.g. `{int(k): v for k,v in dict_to_sort.items()}` would work

Comment: Also, I think the proposed solutions are only valid for python 3.7 or greater.  Previous versions do not respect dict insertion ordering.

Comment: Thank you. Yes Indeed converting it into int fixed the issue. Didn't thought of converting the string to int would solve the issue.... Thank you all for your answers. Vaduva Mihaita Bogdan and anon01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort as `int`.

```
dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:int(x[0])))
```

```
{'-26': 1,
 '-25': 0,
 '-24': 0,
 '-23': 1,
 '-22': 8,
 '-21': 17,
 '-20': 19,
 '-19': 10,
 '-18': 24,
 '-17': 26,
 '-16': 16,
 '-15': 17,
 '-14': 16,
 '-13': 20,
 '-12': 16,
 '-11': 17,
 '-10': 7,
 '-9': 4,
 '-8': 11,
 '-7': 9,
 '-6': 6,
 '-5': 9,
 '-4': 3,
 '-3': 1,
 '-2': 1,
 '0': 4,
 '1': 4}
```